# I wouled like to ask for the flight ticket from lao to canada

Tags: tickets, transit-visas, seoul, laotian-citizens

I am a Lao citizen. I am planning to buy a one way flight ticket from Vientiane to St. John’s NL  (Canada) and I will passed in Seoul incheon (Icn) airport.

Do I need a visa?
Thanks,
Siri

Comment: Are you asking if you need a visa to transit Seoul or to go to Canada? Or both? Do you already have a visa for Canada?

Answer (score 3):

Lao citizens need a [temporary resident visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/about-visitor-visa.html) (this is the official name Canada gives to visitor visas) to visit Canada. You need to obtain the visa before you depart.

You do not need a visa to transit through Seoul and remain in the airport transit area. You are allowed to leave the airport on Korea's transit tourist program for a brief tour of the city, if you have sufficient time between your flights.

You will likely be denied boarding, or denied entry to Canada, if you have a one way ticket.

---

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in part:

> Korea (Rep.) (KR)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Seoul
>   (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international
>   transit area of the airport and have documents required for
>   the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Seoul
>   (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 72 hours. They must:
>
> - join a transit tour organized by Seoul (ICN), and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

(For Canada, visa exemptions exist but none apply to you, so they are not shown here.)

> Canada (CA)
>
> Warning:
>
> - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused
>     entry.